# Examples with suffix 完 (かん)

Tags: grammar, suffixes

According to Jisho, 完 (かん) can be used as a suffix with meanings "completion; conclusion; end​" and "providing fully".

https://jisho.org/search/%E5%AE%8C

However, I can't find any example of 完 used as a suffix for any of both cases.

Could you please give me an example or some if possible with suffix 完?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. 完 is used to indicate the end of an entire work (similarly to "Fin"), but the same kanji is also used to indicate the end of a part/chapter. For example, on the last page of a volume of a novel, you may see "第二部完" (End of Part II) or "X編・完" (X Arc Complete). Not all novels use this kind of notation. I don't know if this is technically a suffix, though...
2. 完 meaning "providing fully" is an abbreviation of 完備. You find this mainly (or almost exclusively) in real estate ads. For example:

   > ◯◯駅まで徒歩8分！ システムキッチン・エアコン完！

Comment: +1. Additionally, there's n完 (1完, 2完, ..., 全完) in the context of examinations (usually university entrance exams) where you completely answer n questions (rather *sections*? Each subject {math, history,...} ) has some sections, and each section has typically several questions.).

Comment: @naruto Thank you very much for your answer. It helped a lot. :)